# How to: Read from a dictionary and append to it

Tags: python

What I want to do is, everytime a user makes a new entry, the `dictionary` should be doing a new entry into my `list_1.txt` and then read back from it. 
I got the `"adding content to list_1.txt"` part but I don't know how I possibly could make my `dictonary` read back from it.

```
def dictionary():
    dict1 = {"name": "xyz",
             "age": 25,
             "hobby": "Dancing"}

if input("Do you want to update the values?[y/n]: ") == "y":
    dict1["name"] = str(input("Change the name to: "))
    print(dict1["name"])
    dict1["age"] = int(input("Change the age to: "))
    print(dict1["age"])
    dict1["hobby"] = str(input("Change the hobby to: "))
    print(dict1["hobby"])
elif input() != "y":
    print("No valid input");
elif input() == "n":
    print("Here is the current Data: " + str(dict1))
    sys.exit()
print(dict1)

appendFile = open('list_1.txt','a')
appendFile.write("\n" + str(dict1))
appendFile.close()
```

This is the current state of the code. I already tried creating `"readMe = open("list_1.txt","r").read()"` and calling it inside `"dict1"` but as you can imagine it went horribly wrong. I'd be grateful for anykind of help and advice you could contribute. 
P.S: I know my menu is buggy but I didn't put any time into it yet. This is just a little project to learn python.

Comment: Look into `JSON` or `pickle`.

Comment: There is a lot wrong with this code. Every time you call `input` it will prompt again, which doesn't make sense for your outer conditional code. Write some new code, and absolute minimum to demonstrate the problem that you don't know how to solve. See how to create a [mcve] for ideas.

Comment: I noticed there is a lot wrong with my code but I did not know how to fix it yet. I'll look more into it. Maybe that'll fix my problems :D
Thanks for your contribution. @PeterWood

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's easy to do so with the [JSON module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html), which stores Python objects into a storage format called [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON).

Add a check in the beginning of your function to see if the file exists. If it doesn't use your default values for the dictionary, otherwise load the data from the file.

```
def dictionary():
    if os.path.exists('list_1.txt'): # load dictionary if exists
        with open('list_1.txt', 'r') as f:
            dict1 = json.load(f)
    else:
        dict1 = { # otherwise use default values
            "name": "xyz",
            "age": 25,
            "hobby": "Dancing"
        }
```

When the program is done, output the data to a text file:

```
    with open('list_1.txt', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(dict1, f)
```

Final program:

```
import os
import sys
import json

def dictionary():
    if os.path.exists('list_1.txt'): # load dictionary if exists
        with open('list_1.txt', 'r') as f:
            dict1 = json.load(f)
    else:
        dict1 = { # otherwise use default values
            "name": "xyz",
            "age": 25,
            "hobby": "Dancing"
        }
        
    if input("Do you want to update the values?[y/n]: ") == "y":
        dict1["name"] = str(input("Change the name to: "))
        print(dict1["name"])
        dict1["age"] = int(input("Change the age to: "))
        print(dict1["age"])
        dict1["hobby"] = str(input("Change the hobby to: "))
        print(dict1["hobby"])
    elif input() != "y":
        print("No valid input");
    elif input() == "n":
        print("Here is the current Data: " + str(dict1))
        sys.exit()
    print(dict1)

    with open('list_1.txt', 'w') as f: # save dict
        json.dump(dict1, f)
```

Comment: Hey! First of all thanks for your contribution :)
I tried your approach and it gave me a whole lot of error messages.
See here: https://www.paste.org/107788

Comment: This error might occur if there is already data in the file from before you run this code. If you delete the file and try again, this code should automatically create a new file and run afterwards

Answer (score -1):

use json module in python

```
import json

#assming folling is content of your text file
# {
#     "name": "xyz",
#     "age": 25,
#     "hobby": "Dancing"
# }


#context manager // auto close file outside "with" clause
with open("list_1.txt",'r') as file:

    #convert  string '{"name": "xyz","age": 25, "hobby": "Dancing" }' into
    #dictionary dict1
    dict1=json.loads( file.read()  )  


if input("Do you want to update the values?[y/n]: ") == "y":
    dict1["name"] = str(input("Change the name to: "))
    print(dict1["name"])
    dict1["age"] = int(input("Change the age to: "))
    print(dict1["age"])
    dict1["hobby"] = str(input("Change the hobby to: "))
    print(dict1["hobby"])
elif input() != "y":
    print("No valid input");
elif input() == "n":
    print("Here is the current Data: " + str(dict1))
    sys.exit()
print(dict1)

# appendFile = open('list_1.txt','a')
# appendFile.write("\n" + str(dict1))
# appendFile.close()

#use this instead
with  open('list_1.txt','w') as file:
    #convert dict to string
    content = json.dumps(dict1)
    file.write(content)
```

you can also use numpy

```
np.save('list_1.npy', dictionary)
#file extension must me .npy
```

Comment: Hi, I also tried your approach but it's the same story. I don't know if it's my shitty code that causes the problems. I'll try to make an actually good terminal menu and try your approach again. Thanks for the help so far :)
See here for error codes: https://www.paste.org/107789